# Jenkins slaves on docker container keep getting no space found errors

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins, docker-container, jenkins-agent

My Jenkins slaves, that are running in docker containers, keep getting out of space errors. While that is fine, i'm trying to find a way to monitor the disk storage stats of the containers and send a notification whenever the space is about to get empty?

Answer (score 0):

Use volumes mounted to the container for storage. That way you can monitor the disk-space on your container host and take appropriate action.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/